# Could not get JDBC Connection / Transaction is not active

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I'm struggling with a call to my database through Spring Jdbc, none of the questions on stack overflow worked for me so that's why I am asking it.

Here's my DAO

```
public class CruDao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements ICruDao{

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CruDao.class);

    @Override
    public String obtainCode(String codiModel) {
        String code = null;

        SimpleJdbcCall funcio = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate()).withFunctionName("funcCru");
        MapSqlParameterSource parameter = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("id", codiModel);

        try {
            code = funcio.executeFunction(String.class, parameter);
            LOG.debug("Generated Code: " + code);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            LOG.error("Error",ex);
        }

        return codiCRU;
    }

}
```

Here's the exception it throws when calls the `executeFunction` line:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error retreiving database metadata; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f5796c1:d4ac:5e1c3647:9ff status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f5796c1:d4ac:5e1c3647:9ff status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >)
```

I have correctly declared the beans for the datasource with the information of the database.
[image]

**EDIT**
The method where I call my DAO was already @Transactional

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public byte[] obtenirModel(String codiModel) {

        byte[] genDocByteArray = null;

        codiCRU = cruDao.obtainCode(codiModel);

        if(codiCRU == null || codiCRU.length() < 1){
            log.error("Errorrr");
            return null;
        }

        ...
```

What I am missing? Thanks in advise.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. there is no active transaction. The fact that you define a transactionmanager doesn't mean you have a transaction. You still have to mark code/methods transactional. Please add the xml config as text instead of images, the latter is quite unreadable.

Comment: Sorry about the unreadable xml, by the way the method where I call my DAO was already Transactional. Should the interface of my DAO also have the Transactional annotation? @M.Deinum

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` wihtout having a `<tx:annotation-driven />` in XML doesn't make it transactional.

Comment: Did you enable transaction management (either through an annotation (`@EnableTransactionManagement` on a config class), or through xml config (`<tx:annotation-driven/>`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an active transaction while accessing the db. You have defined the transaction manager bean in your xml, but not using it.You need to annotate the service method `@Transactional` who is calling this `obtainCode` method. Also note that, `@Transactional` annotated method needs to be public and called from another bean(due to proxying mechanism), to make it work properly.

Comment: I already had the Transactional annotation in the method where I call my DAO so what I'm missing?? Should the interface of my DAO also have the @Transactional annotation?

Comment: shouldn't be necessary to have it on interface. And you checked that @Transactional annotated method is public and called from another bean? you can share some code snippet of the caller.